# Emotions in Animals Based on Neuroscience

Tags: neuroscience, animal-psychology

I know very little about the subject, so please forgive any misunderstandings in the question. First of all, by emotion, I mean feelings of pleasure and suffering and not merely just sensory recognition of damage to the body or things like that. If I understand correctly, the consensus among scientists is that all mammals can feel pleasure and pain based upon all of these animals having similar brain structures to humans that have been correlated with feelings like pleasure and suffering. https://www.emory.edu/LIVING_LINKS/publications/articles/deWaal_2011b.pdf.  The way I'm hoping to potentially find an answer is by asking if it's known that there are certain structures in the human brain that are necessary for feeling pleasure and suffering and if it's known that are any animals that do not have these structures or similar structures?

Comment: Hi and Welcome! You may not know that this site requires evidence of prior research (quote and link to source/s) in an attempt to answer your own question (this is a Q&A site, but one with slightly higher expectations.) For example, you can search using terms like "dog emotion and MRI", and quote from the article. Showing evidence or research greatly increases your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: look up the amygdala

Comment: What is it about the paper that doesn't answer your question? A link alone gives us no information.

Comment: It is so broad that I wrote my thesis on it! The evidence is also inconclusive and dividing. I think this is too broad for this site. Here is a fairly recent review on the subject https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0149763419305391